# What are the algebraic structures of the wallpaper groups?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, reference-request

The wallpaper groups are discrete groups of affine motions in the plane that contain two linearly independent translations.  Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group

Some of them have very straightforward structures, like $$\textrm{pm}=\textrm{Dih}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\textrm{pg}=\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}\quad\textrm{(non-trivial semidirect product)}$$

But the structure of $\textrm{p2gg}$, which is generated by two orthogonal glide reflections, is not straightforward at all.  What is the structure of this group?  Is there a general reference which contains the structures of all the wallpaper groups?

Comment: Isn't the list/classification of the wallpaper groups precisely what you ask for?

Comment: I've seen numerous papers that list/classify the wallpaper groups, but none of them seem to give the abstract structures.

Comment: Presentations for the wallpaper groups are given in Coxeter and Moser, *Generators and Relations for Discrete Groups*, Chapter 4 and Table 3.

Answer (score 2):

By the Bieberbach theorems, such a group $\Gamma$, being a discrete cocompact subgroup of 
$$Isom(\mathbb{R}^2)=O_2(\mathbb{R})\rtimes T(2),$$ has a normal subgroup $N\simeq \mathbb{Z}^2$ of finite index, consisting of translations. Its point group $F=\Gamma/N$ is finite, and is one of the $10$ groups $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,C_6,D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_6$. $\Gamma$ is then an extension of $F$ by $N$, i.e., we have the short exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow \Gamma\rightarrow F\rightarrow 1.
$$
There are exactly $17$ such different $\Gamma$, and their structure can be described explicitly, e.g., by giving explicit generators and relations for these groups, see the thesis of [Antje Meiser](http://docserv.uni-duesseldorf.de/servlets/DerivateServlet/Derivate-2046/46.pdf), which gives in addition the zeta functions for all $17$ groups.

Example. The presentation for $p2gg$ is given by $$\langle x,y,u,v \mid [x,y],u^2 = x,v^2 = y,xv = x^{−1},yu = y^{−1},(uv)^2 \rangle$$

Comment: Can you describe the structures of the 17 $\Gamma$ explicitly then?

Comment: Yes, one can describe this explicitly for all $17$ groups, see chapter $2$ of Ante's thesis.