# prove wallpaper groups are not isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, rotations, symmetry, reflection, rigid-transformation

In the chapter I am reading on wallpaper groups, it outlines proofs that all the wallpaper groups are not isomorphic and hence different. But I do not fully see why what they are saying is true.

For example, it says that $p4mm$ and $p4gm$ are not isomorphic because the 4-fold rotation $(\textbf{a}, A_{\pi/2})$ in $p4gm$ cannot be written as the product of two reflections in $p4gm$, whilst each 4-fold rotation in $p4mm$ can be factorised as two reflections in $p4mm$.

* $A_{\pi/2}$ is the rotation matrix of order 4

Is someone able to show the steps it takes to conclude this?

The notation is that used by Armstrong in Groups and Symmetry.

Comment: What book does the chapter belong to?

Comment: @Shaun Armstrong's Groups and Symmetry

Comment: A different idea is to use the known presentations and the abstract structure of the wallpaper groups. Then it is easy to see that they are pairwise non-isomorphic. For a reference, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510105/what-are-the-algebraic-structures-of-the-wallpaper-groups?rq=1).